# Yii renderPartial index view redirects when page changes

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii

So I want to partially render another Controller's index page(Controller's name is ObavjestenjaController) inside my site/index page, within a div. I defined actionIndexPartial in that other Controller and it looks like this:

```
public function actionIndexPartial()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Obavjestenja', array(
        'pagination' => array('pageSize'=>3,),
    ));
    $this->renderPartial('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

In my site/index, I have this div:

```
<div id="obavjestenjadiv">
    <?php
        Yii::app()->runController('Obavjestenja/indexPartial');
    ?>
</div>
```

And the page is displayed in the required div. What fails is page swapping from CListView. By default, it wants to redirect me to obavjestenja/index&Obavjestenja_page=2 page when I change to 2nd page, but I want to remain within the same page(site/index), and the page to be changed correctly within the div. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:** The AJAX by default was redirecting me there. I edited my div in site/index by creating custom CListView widget there, providing it with dataProvider from the corresponding Model and displaying the results in it. Works like charm.

site/index div:

```
<?php 
    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Obavjestenja', array(
        'pagination' => array('pageSize'=>3,),
    ));
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'itemView'=>'//obavjestenja/_view',
    )); 
?>
```

The only thing is, when the AJAX refreshes CListView, it returns me to the top of the page. Can I avoid this? Thanks and hope my solution helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In your Site/Index try using RenderPartial instead of RunController.

Use below code between `<div>` tag.

```
$this->renderPartial('//Obavjestenja/indexPartial');
```

Here is full code

```
<div id="obavjestenjadiv">
<?php $this->renderPartial('//Obavjestenja/indexPartial'); ?>
</div>
```